# Generate/Simulate noise for images in Python to resemble high ISO shoot

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, dataset

I am trying to generate some noisy images to train my model. The problem is I could not find any library that does so realistically.

For example, with this images:

[image: make-picture-less-grainy-1.jpg]

I tried to use the `skimage.util.random_noise` with variable grain size (default is always 1 pixel) but still I cannot replicate the noise as shown in the picture.

Any idea how to replicate such noise. It seems to be caused by using camera with high ISO settings.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the "noise" generated from high-ISO image are actually the result of the denoising process done by the camera.

Try to use `fastNlMeansDenoisingColored` can provide some good result

```
def denoise(img):
    im_arr = np.asarray(img)
    dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(im_arr, None, 10, 10, 7, 21)
    return Image.fromarray(dst)
```